# Windows launch process with/without console

Tags: c, windows

I use c system() function in my application to launch commands like these:

```
cmd.exe /c a.bat
guiapp.exe
consoleapp.exe
```

It works, however, system() launches guiapp.exe with console displayed (which, obviously, is not used in this gui app). How to launch new process considering the fact that I don't know whether process to be launched should display console? I want to launch the process in the same way as the process would be launched when double clicked by mouse.

Comment: Have you tried the `exec` function family?

Comment: @WeatherVane, don't use `exec*`. Use [`spawn*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=vs-2017) to stay with the CRT or call [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) directly.

Comment: How do you compile `guiapp.exe`? If using MinGW/gcc you need to add the linker option `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` to your compiler command line.

Comment: I don't compile guiapp or consoleapp, these are third party apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CreateProcess` and in the `dwFlags` parameter do not specify `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` as one of the flags.

This way, if the application is a GUI app, it will not launch a console window, and if it is a console app, it will run in the same console as the launching process.

Example code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi, pi2;
    STARTUPINFO si, si2;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    CreateProcessW(L"C:\\GUIAppDir\\GUIApp.exe", L"program-arguments-here", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, NULL, L"C:\\GUIAppDir", &si, &pi);

    ZeroMemory(&pi2, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&si2, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    si2.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    CreateProcessW(L"C:\\ConsoleAppDir\\ConsoleApp.exe", L"program-arguments-here", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, NULL, L"C:\\ConsoleAppDir", &si2, &pi2);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi2.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi2.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi2.hProcess);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the wording here suggests to me that `system` ultimately uses `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, but it does not. It executes the command via the cmd.exe shell, which, like any console application, defaults to inheriting the parent's console or otherwise allocating a new console. When running a child GUI app from a parent GUI app that has no console, and given cmd.exe is run with `/c` to wait on the child process, we get an empty console window that serves no purpose.

Comment: We get complete control if we call `CreateProcess` and omit cmd.exe from the command line, but `_wspawn*` with `_P_WAIT` would be similar and simpler, IMO.